# Get index number of item at the top of a Listview OnDisappear in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to get the index number of a listview cell that is on the top of the ListView when OnDisappear?

I am trying to store the position of the listview when a user tabs to clicks a modal, and restore it later OnAppear.

Comment: The top index of list view is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ItemAppearing event

```
var listView = new ListView { ... };

listView.ItemAppearing += async (sender, e) =>
{
    // get index of e.Item + add count of items available at visual
};
```